# Clojure function literal #() gotcha

Tags: macros, clojure

I'm in the process of refactoring my code to make it simpler. The evolution has gone like this, starting with:

```
(defn board-changed
      "called when current-board changes"
  [fr _ _ _ _]
  (repaint! (select fr [:#canvas])))
```

Then in another function:

```
.
.
(add-watch the-board :board (partial board-changed fr))
.
.
```

I decided that I didn't really need a separate function, board-changed, I could instead define it anonymously inline and in the process remove the need for (partial), and remove the need to lookup the canvas every time, which led to this code:

```
.
.
(let [cnv (select fr [:#canvas])]
  (add-watch the-board :board (fn [_ _ _ _] (repaint! cnv))))
.
.
```

This code works.

The next step I decided was to simplify further by using the #() macro however I discovered that the code below does not work:

```
.
.
(let [cnv (select fr [:#canvas])]
  (add-watch the-board :board #(repaint! cnv)))
.
.
```

It silently fails: the first time the watch is called the programme falls into a blackhole: no errors or exceptions.

What's gone wrong?

Answer (score 4):

This is [how agent errors work](http://clojure.org/agents). You're first failure is cached, the next will occur immediately.

> If any exceptions are thrown by an action function, no nested dispatches will occur, and the exception will be cached in the Agent itself. When an Agent has errors cached, any subsequent interactions will immediately throw an exception, until the agent's errors are cleared. Agent errors can be examined with agent-error and the agent restarted with restart-agent.

You can check for first failure errors with `agent-error` or register an error handler with 
 `set-error-handler!`

---

```
so.core=> (def a (agent 0))
#'so.core/a

so.core=> (add-watch a :key #(println "foo"))
#<Agent@766245a4: 0>

so.core=> (set-error-handler! a (fn [the-agent the-exception] (println "bar")))
nil

so.core=> (send a inc)
#<Agent@766245a4: 1>
bar

so.core=> (agent-error a)
#<ArityException clojure.lang.ArityException: 
  Wrong number of args (4) passed to: core/eval1299/fn--1300>

so.core=> (send a inc)
ArityException 
  Wrong number of args (4) passed to: core/eval1299/fn--1300  
  clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity (AFn.java:429)
```

Comment: Thank you! I had a suspicion it was due to it being in an agent function but couldn't find any details.

Answer (score 3):

`add-watch` requires a function of 4 arguments. Using the anonymous function literal `#(...)` without argument literals makes the reader produce a function of no arguments.

To save space you can write `(fn [& _] ...)`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd seen behaviour like this before when passing invalid parameters: you'll either get an exception because you've passed in an unexpected type or you've passed in an invalid number of parameters (which strangely does not always seem to throw an exception!).

This turned out to be an example of the latter: wrong number of parameters. But why?

The first thing I did was to macro expand:

```
(clojure.pprint/pprint (macroexpand '#(repaint! cnv)))
=> (fn* [] (repaint! cnv))
```

That gave me my first clue: I had assumed the #() flexibility with function arguments, the ability to refer to them as %, %1, %2 etc was provided at run-time.

And macro-expanding the form below confirmed it:

```
(clojure.pprint/pprint (macroexpand '(add-watch the-board :board #(repaint! %4))))
=> (fn* [p1__7764# p2__7765# p3__7766# p4__7763#] (repaint! p4__7763#))
```

The #() looks at the body for the % with highest number, in this case 4, and assumes there are that many arguments to the function, so in this case 4. (Those funny argument names are gensyms).

So the problem I was encountering was that the function I pass to add-watch must take exactly 4 arguments, but the function being generated by #() took zero.

So the conclusion is (fn arg-list body) can only be replaced with #(body) when the body references the last argument passed in.

So

```
(fn [_ _ _ arg4] (println arg4))
```

could be replaced by

```
#(println %4)
```

But

```
(fn [_ _ _ _] (println "hello world")
```

can not be replaced by

```
#(println "hello world")
```

I have to admit that I was surprised that you don't get a runtime arity exception!